# xerces sax last html double quotes in a value is ignored

Tags: c++, xml, sax, xerces, xerces-c

I am using Xerces SAX to parse an XML file.

Values between 2 HTML quotes are not correctly parsed, Only one quote is displayed the last one isn't. Example :

```
<Rating_Text>&quot;a3&quot;</Rating_Text>
```

is parsed as :

```
"a3
```

Whereas it should be

```
"a3"
```

How to fix that please ?

```
//...
m_pXMLReader->setFeature(XMLUni::fgSAX2CoreValidation, true);
//...
void CXMLMsg::characters(
const   XMLCh* const    chars,
const   XMLSize_t       length
)
{
   char* szData = XMLString::transcode(chars);
if(!isspace(*szData))
{
//
}
XMLString::release(&szData);
}
```

In debug mode, I checked that in "chars" the last double quotes is not present and the length is correct (it doesnt include the last double quote). It sounds like Xerces is ignoring the last "

If I replace html code for double quotes with real quotes ", I got the entire value in the callback... so why in the case of using HTML code to represent the double quotes, Xerces decide to split the string ??

Comment: `&quot;` would be `"` and not `'`. And can you show your code, please?

Comment: SAX can be odd, are you sure you are not simply getting two or more calls to the `characters` event handler, where the second call has the second quote? I don't think there is a guarantee with SAX that you get the complete character data in one call.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes you are right ! I just checked it !! but this is very embarrassing ! I need to get all the string (which is small as you can see) in one call ! how to predict that the string value is not complete ? oh my gosh !

Comment: I have added the tag for SAX to your question, hopefully someone else can tell you more on SAX, I mostly use XSLT or at least tree models like DOM, where there are convenient ways or properties like `textContent` to get the complete text inside of an element node.

Comment: Thank you, I really don't wanna add some extra code to handle this type of situation, it will add complexity to my "already complex" generic XML parser (generic to my "work/metier") but I really wanna know why after the character 'a' following a double quote, Xerces decided to cut the string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found an idea, I will put the processing part in endElement callback, and in the characters callback I will just concatenate a string containing the element value ;)